# Inheritance. (A function calling something in a class)

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i've got this function and i want the commands of the drop down menu to refer to a class. How would i set up the class? and the command to communicate to the class? Would i use self.{insert stuff} or...?

```
def main():
  root = Tk()
  menubar = Menu(root)
  file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
  menubar.add_cascade(label="File    ", menu=file_menu)
  file_menu.add_command(label="Open    ", command = <insert way to communicate to above class)
```

Sorry if this isn't making sense. Please help

Comment: What *"above class"*? What (if anything) does this have to do with inheritance?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, wild to see where I was and where I am now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

say you've got

```
class MyClass:
    def my_func(self):
        pass
my_obj = MyClass()
```

if you want to have `add_command` use `my_func` through `my_obj` you can

```
file_menu.add_command(label="Open    ", command=my_obj.my_func)
```

Functions are just data in python, you can pass them like they were a variable.